# Creating read only classes from XSD files using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like for the classes produced by the JAXB code generator to have no set methods included within them.

I have attempted this within the GUI provided by eclipse by selecting the read-only option, but the output still contains all of the set methods.

How would I go about generating these classes without the set methods included?

Comment: The the goal is to have classes with only getters just returning `null`?

Comment: The goal is to have an immutable class. I can delete all of the set methods manually after generation and the code operates fine and as expected.

Comment: I don't believe there is a simple way out there.  You can write a pluggin for XJC to generate the code however you wish.  See these active plugins for examples (the annotation one is most like what you want) https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Home

Comment: This could be of use: https://github.com/sabomichal/immutable-xjc